# One to Many relationship between two Entities when both entities has composite primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

Relationship in my Oracle DB:

A may have  many B
B will have only one A

so from A side ----> one to Many

From B side ---> Many to one .

I care about only unidirectinal relationship   a---b  (one to many)   , mean whenever i access A i want to get the set of B joining five columns (A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)

A Primary key

A1
A2
A3
A4
A5

so it means A has composite primary key   A1,A2,A3,A4,A5

B Primary key

A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6

so it means A has composite primary key   A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6      ( A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 is coming as foreign key)

This is leagcy DB and i can not play with DB, So i want to create relationship between A to B .  I need to handle this using mapping,  Is this possible ????

Please post if you know if your answer will really works ,because I have tried everything . And I m not hibernate immature .

I  really need help on this .

Comment: For better help, post your attempt and explain how it "didn't work" (e.g. do you encounter exceptions or undesired behavior?)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to define two @Embeddable entities to represent the composite keys for A and B. BKey is identical to AKey except that it adds "a6" property.

AKey Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class AKey implements Serializable {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;
    private String a4;
    private String a5;

    public AKey() {
    }

    public AKey(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
        this.a4 = a4;
        this.a5 = a5;
    }

    ... // getters & setters
}
```

Then you define your A class to use the Embeddable composite key class as the @IdClass but still use the composite key elements as properties.  You would do the same thing for the B class (using BKey).  Define the @OneToMany mapping in A for the "Set bs" property with the required @JoinColumns.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AKey.class)
public class A {

    @Id
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;
    private String a4;
    private String a5;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=B.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) 
        @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="a1"), @JoinColumn(name="a2"), 
        @JoinColumn(name="a3"), @JoinColumn(name="a4"), @JoinColumn(name="a5")})
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();

    public A() {
    }

    public A(AKey id, String prop1) {
        this.a1 = id.getA1();
        this.a2 = id.getA2();
        this.a3 = id.getA3();
        this.a4 = id.getA4();
        this.a5 = id.getA5();
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public Set<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }
    public void setBs(Set<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }

    ... // getters & setters and anything else in A
}
```

I didn't have any issues with this approach - it expected the table structure you defined (A with a 5-column primary key, B with a 6-column primary key and a 5-column foreign key to A).

The following test case correctly created an A with 2 associated Bs that could be retrieved using JQL.

```
B b = new B(new BKey("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "1"), "prop1");
B b2 = new B(new BKey("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "2"), "prop1");
A a = new A(new AKey("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), "prop1");
a.getBs().add(b);
a.getBs().add(b2);

manager.persist(a);


....
```

Hope this helps.

Sarah